# Problem in Delete Index by name from Elasticsearch using java clients

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I am using Elasticsearch 6.5.4 version and when I delete one index by its name using below codes it is working fine but when I try to search using the deleted index name instead of getting "**no such index**" message I get some documents which are present in some other indices.

**But before deletion** of that index when I search with the same query I got the results only from that index, strange!!!

1.Delete index using Low level Rest Client

```
Request req  = new Request("DELETE",  "/"+allData.getIndexName());
Response response = getElasticRestClient().performRequest(req);
```

2.Delete index using High Level Rest Client

```
DeleteIndexRequest request = new DeleteIndexRequest(allData.getIndexName());
AcknowledgedResponse deleteIndexResponse = client.indices().delete(request, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
```

I have tried both of these and in both the cases index got deleted successfully but facing the same issue while searching with the deleted indexname.

Now, I have deleted all the indices first and then checked for GET _cat/indices and GET _cat/aliases where I got **"[]"**.

Then I have created 2 indices with the name "action_movies" and "superhero_movies" and added 3 documents for each index.

[image: 1st index]
[image: 2nd index]

Now when I checked for GET _cat/aliases got **[]** as before.
And for GET _cat/indices got

```
["superhero_movies",
 "action_movies"]
```

Now when I searched the index "action_movies" and got following results
[image: action_movies]

with "superhero_movies" got following results
[image: superhero_movies]

Then deleted the index **"action_movies"** and repeated GET _cat/aliases and got **[]** 
then GET _cat/indices and got

```
["action_movies"]
```

And Finally I search for **"action_movies"** I got the following result(the documents belongs to the index **"superhero_movies"**) instead of "no such index".

[image]

Comment: What is the concrete index name you're deleting and then what is the concrete index name you're getting data from after deletion?

Comment: @Val {"indexName":"sanjh_test_local"}

Comment: What do you get when running `GET _cat/indices` and `GET _cat/aliases` after before and after deleting your index. Please update your question with the results.

Comment: @Val I have edited the post, could you please check now?

Comment: I'm interested to see the results you get directly from Elasticsearch and not through another proxy framework that acts as middleman between Postman and ES.

Comment: @Val Yes, it is working fine in Kibana(getting the expected result after deletion i.e. "no such index found").

Comment: Yes, then the problem is not Elasticsearch but whatever you have in the middle.